# Parameter -ExcludeProperty disables table name from SQL

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, powershell

I am creating an HTML report with PowerShell which displays several SQL queries. Now I have the problem, that `-ExcludeProperty` from `Select-Object` disables given table names of SQL queries.

At the moment I am excluding this: 'RowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors', but I need to exclude 'Table' too. But if I am excluding it, given names will be replaced by '*'.

This query:

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS 'Files in queue' FROM ...
```

is for example displayed this way:

```
 ---------
|____*____|
|______37_|
```

Can you help?

Edit:
Thanks for your feedback! Double quote is not working. Also if i write Files_in_queue i get the same output. 
This is my output statement:

```
$dataSet.Tables[0] |
  Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors, Table |
  ConvertTo-Html –Body $body |
  Out-File -Append $OutputFile
```

It's showing me the result of above mentioned SQL statement but with a `*` in the table header, not with the `AS`-text.

This is how I get the SQL result:

```
$connectionDetails = "Provider=sqloledb; " +
                     "Data Source=$dataSourceActual; " +
                     "Initial Catalog=$databaseActual; " +
                     "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionDetails
$command = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand $sqlCommandActual,$connection
$connection.Open()

$dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
$connection.Close()

$dataSet.Tables[0] |
  Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors, Table |
  ConvertTo-Html –Body $body |
  Out-File -Append $OutputFile
```

**Edit 2:**

```
$props = $dataSet.Tables[0] |
         Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors, Table -First 1 |
         ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name }

$dataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Html –Body $body -Property $props |
  Out-File -Append $OutputFile
```

Error:

```
ConvertTo-Html : System.Management.Automation.PSObject can not be converted in
the following type: {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
Bei C:\temp\html_test.ps1:138 Zeichen:15
+ ConvertTo-Html <<<<  –Body $body -Property $props |
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-Html], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToHtmlCommand
```

**Edit 3:**

This is the convertion to string of `$props`:

```
[string]$props = $dataSet.Tables[0] |
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors, Table -First 1 |
    ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object * -Expand Name }
```

and the output statement:

```
$dataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Html –Body $body -Property $props |
  Out-File -Append $OutputFile
```

How can I build a loop, that the above mentioned code is only applied for one-column tables? I tried this:

```
if ($dataSet.Length = 1) {
    [string]$props = $dataSet.Tables[0] |
        Select-Object * -ExcludePropertyRowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors, Table -First 1 |
        ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object * -Expand Name }
} else {
    [string]$props = $dataSet.Tables[0] |
        Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray, HasErrors, Table |
        ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object * -Expand Name }
}
```

I tried also `$dataSet.Tables[0].Length` in the `if` clause and `-eq 1` as condition.

Comment: Please show your PowerShell code as well as an example of actual *and* desired output.

Comment: try to use double quote - SELECT count(*) AS "Files in queue" FROM ...

Comment: Your comment is unreadable. Please edit your question and put that information there.

Comment: Sorry. Question has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you observe seems to happen when the input for `ConvertTo-Html` has just one property. You'd get the same column header if for instance you selected only the `Table` property:

```
... | Select-Object Table | ConvertTo-Html -Body $body
```

Output:

```html
...
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>*</th></tr>
<tr><td>Table</td></tr>
<tr><td>Table</td></tr>
...
</table>
...
```

The reason for this behavior isn't clear to me, but you can mitigate it by specifying the desired column title via the `-Property` parameter of the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet:

```
... | Select-Object Table | ConvertTo-Html -Body $body -Property 'Files in queue'
```

Output:

```html
...
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Files in queue</th></tr>
<tr><td>Table</td></tr>
<tr><td>Table</td></tr>
...
</table>
...
```

You don't even need the `Select-Object` step here, since the `-Property` parameter of `ConvertTo-Html` already selects the specified property.

If you know that there'll be only one column and know the value you're going to use as the column title, you could define your query string like this:

```
$coltitle = 'Files in queue'
$sqlCommandActual = "SELECT count(*) AS `"$coltitle`" FROM ..."
```

and process the table like this:

```
$dataSet.Tables[0] |
  ConvertTo-Html –Body $body -Property $coltitle |
  Out-File -Append $OutputFile
```

If you don't know the column title (because you're calling a stored procedure or whatever) you can determine it on the fly like this:

```
$props = $dataSet.Tables[0] |
         Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, ItemArray,
           HasErrors, Table -First 1 |
         ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name }

$dataSet.Tables[0] |
  ConvertTo-Html –Body $body -Property $props |
  Out-File -Append $OutputFile
```

This works for a single or multiple properties alike.

Comment: First, thanks for your detailed answer! Last code-snippet is relevant for me, because i know the column titles, but i'm processing more SQL statements within a if-loop and the Out-File is every time the same.

Comment: Please see 'Edit2'. ConvertTo-Html seems to expect an string object... Can you help here again?

Comment: @ch41n54w `$props` should be a string or array of strings. Check the output of `$props.GetType().FullName` and `$props | % { $_.GetType().FullName }`. Also check the type of `$body`.

Comment: Great, thanks! $props was of the type System.Object[].
Now, the single-column tables have their header, but the other tables are not written out.
i tried to check the .length of $ dataSet, so that i can Loop around. Please see Edit3...

Comment: @ch41n54w There were 2 commands in my previous comment. What was the type of the *elements* of `$props`? And why do you now have `Select-Object * -Expand Name` and cast the result to a string? Simply expanding the `Name` property (*without* the spurious `*`) should already give you either a string or an array of strings.

Comment: Ah, ok. Changed that. Now `$props.GetType().FullName` is `System.Object[]`
`$props | % { $_.GetType().FullName }` is `System.String`

Comment: @ch41n54w For all array elements? Then `ConvertTo-Html` shouldn't be throwing that error.

Comment: Yes, for all elements. Now the error isn't thrown anymore. The one-column-only queries have now the header. But all other queries are not shown.

Comment: Sorry, i'm no native speaker. Maybe it wasn't clear enough. Im processing twelve sql queries with a if-loop. And the results with only one column and line have the header problem. Now this is solved, but the other queries will not be given out. Before your help they were given out.

Comment: @ch41n54w Again, that goes beyond the scope of what you asked in this question. Please post a new question for that. Do not move the target.

Comment: Ok, i will do. Thank you.